# Is it possible to redirect authenticated Azure AD users (by ROPC) to Microsoft Teams?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have been working on the development of a portal for a long time and one of the important modules of this portal is that it can login to 3rd party systems without asking username/password. It can be called a simple SSO.

At this point, I am trying to do this for Microsoft Teams :) I have user management authority in Azure AD, so I developed it [with the ROPC user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications-legacy). I successefully get token, but I could not find any document on how to redirect the user to Microsoft Teams page. Is it possible to do this or not?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ROPC only supports a sign in flow. ROPC flow using on other flows(Microsoft teams) there won't be Single sign on, you will be just using the token endpoint. We would recommend you to use other flows if there are any specific requirements with the teams use Microsoft Graph API. And W.r.t Native app SSO using ROPC will not exhibit SSO across apps. Native App SSO using MSAL or any library that can allow cookie sharing across Apps will support SSO.

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
> more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
> requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
> risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
> flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

ROPC involves a user credentials while client creds are application credentials.  More damage can be done if a user identity get stolen. app identity gets stolen you can't easily exploit it the same way as a user.

Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) if you are looking to Develop SSO Microsoft teams tab